# How does Solaris decide the library path?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, solaris, library-path

On Solaris, I can use `crle` command to configure library path like this:

```
crle -c /var/ld/ld.config -l /lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/opt/DSI/32
```

I can also use the traditional `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` method, like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/export/home/donald/mysql-5.0.91-installed/lib/mysql/:/lib:/usr/lib"
```

How does Solaris decide the library path? For example, does Solaris select from `crle path` first, then `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? I try to `google`, but can't find the answers.

Comment: This question belongs on the Unix & Linux SE site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the manual ([man ld.so.1](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ld.so.1+1)).

```
 The runtime linker uses a prescribed search path for  locat-
 ing  the  dynamic  dependencies  of  an  object. The default
 search paths are the runpath recorded in  the  object,  fol-
 lowed  by  a  series  of  defaults.  For 32-bit objects, the
 defaults are /lib followed by /usr/lib. For 64-bit  objects,
 the  defaults  are  /lib/64  followed  by /usr/lib/64. These
 defaults component can be  modified  using  a  configuration
 file  that is created with crle(1). The runpath is specified
 when the dynamic object is constructed using the  -R  option
 to  ld(1).  The  environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH can be
 used to indicate  directories  to  be  searched  before  the
 default directories.
```

So, the order is:

1. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
2. shared object RPATH
3. `crle` defaults